# Как изменить размер дополнительного текста в шаблоне Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, android-navigation-view

Как изменить размер дополнительного текста в шаблоне Navigation Drawer?. Необходимо изменить именно дополнительный текст (на картинке под номером 7). Размер основного  текста меняю без проблем, а вот с дополнительным не могу разобраться. Все перерыл, ничего не нашел.

[image: Необходимо изменить размер элемента под номером 7]

Comment: Покажите как это в коде (в разметке/меню) выглядит. По идее нужно просто найти нужный атрибут стиля

Comment: Возможно тут будет нужная информация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204320/how-can-i-change-the-navigationviews-item-text-size

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но в данном посте обсуждение о том как изменить размер шрифта в основном тексте(на картинке (Recent, Trash и так далее). А вот как изменить размер именно дополнительный шрифт нигде не нашел в документации.

Comment: тут возможно есть интересующая вас информация - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668346/how-to-set-custom-typeface-to-items-in-navigationview

Comment: Там тоже описано как изменить основной текст.